# Caching caches_action fragmens in Memcache and assets in the file system

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

Using Rails 3.1.1 on Heroku, Dalli gem and Memcachier.

I am trying to troubleshoot an issue [where keys disappear from Memcachier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12926781/cached-fragment-does-not-stay-in-memcachier-cache), in order to do this I would like to make sure that only the content from my caches_action will be cached in the memcache. I would like my assets (jpg's etc) to be cached elsewhere.

I believe it is the same issue as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6962896/how-do-i-prevent-rails-3-1-from-caching-static-assets-to-rails-cache) but when I do the same, i.e. adding

```
config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = {
  :metastore    => Dalli::Client.new,
  :entitystore  => 'file:tmp/cache/rack/body',
  :allow_reload => false
}
```

to my production.rb, it doesn't really seem to do anything.

My **production.rb** in full:

```
MyDemoApp::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb

  # Code is not reloaded between requests
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this)
  config.serve_static_assets = true

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS
  config.assets.compress = true

  # Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
  config.assets.compile = true

  # Generate digests for assets URLs
  config.assets.digest = true

  # Defaults to Rails.root.join("public/assets")
  # config.assets.manifest = YOUR_PATH

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile" # for apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for nginx

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # See everything in the log (default is :info)
  # config.log_level = :debug

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags
  # config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :uuid ]

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)

  # Use a different cache store in production
  config.cache_store = :dalli_store 

  config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = {
    :metastore    => Dalli::Client.new,
    :entitystore  => 'file:tmp/cache/rack/body',
    :allow_reload => false
  }  

  # Set expire header of 30 days for static files
  config.static_cache_control = "public, max-age=2592000" 

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://assets.example.com"

  # Precompile additional assets (application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS are already added)
  # config.assets.precompile += %w( search.js )

  # Disable delivery errors, bad email addresses will be ignored
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable threaded mode
  # config.threadsafe!

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation can not be found)
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
end
```

Caching assets work fine (get cache fresh-responses) and caching actions like this:

```
  caches_action :show, :layout => false, :expires_in => 3.days
```

Also creates a cached entry in Rails cache (although they disappear after a while).

**My question now is**: How can I, if possible, do so that only my caches_action fragments end up in my Memcache (and not my assets)?

A bonus question would be, do you see anything out of the ordinary in my production.rb?

Answer (score 0):

I use the gem 'asset_sync' to move all my assets out to Amamzon S3

See Instructions [here](https://github.com/rumblelabs/asset_sync)

You get three advantages:

- Your assets are served from Amazon so the page loads faster for the
  user
- Your slug size on Heroku is smaller and is supposed to be more
  performant
- Your assets will no longer be in memecahce

All my assets cost me about 20cents every three month to host on Amamzon

Comment: Please do not use signatures/taglines in your posts. Your user box counts as your signature, and you can use your profile to post any information about yourself you like. [FAQ on signatures/taglines](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures)